# Enable CPU option from OS not in BIOS

Tags: bios, pci-e

I would like to know if there is any way to enable a specific feature in the CPU, if that feature is not given in the BIOS. For example, i have Xeon E5-2680 V2, according to the data sheet this processor supports NTB on PCIe Port3a. But this NTB option in not given in the BIOS of HP Z420 workstation.
I want to know if there is a possible way to change this PPD register given at page 138 of [pdf](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/xeon-e5-1600-2600-vol-2-datasheet.pdf).

Thank you

Comment: The data sheet you linked says that the register is RW; have you tried to write to it?

Comment: @prl No I did not. I will try and update here.

Comment: @prl So I managed to change the configuration register of PCIe. The thing is that I was not using SUDO and -H flag with setpci command. Below command did my job. 
sudo setpci -H 1 -s 3 4d.B=02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below command did the job.
sudo setpci -H 1 -s 3 4d.B=02